# Null pointer access: The variable b can only be null at this location

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get the above mentioned error in the last line of this following portion of my code.

```
String[][] b = null;
try {
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // use comma as separator
    String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    String[] a=country[1].split(splits);
    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    while(i<a.length) {
      b[j][n]+=a[i];
    }
  }
} catch (...) {}
```

What is the reason for this error and how to solve this?

Comment: Please tag what language is being used.

Answer (score 2):

The only two uses of `b` are

```
b = null;
...
*b[j][n] ...
```

You need to set `b` to an actual array before you can try indexing it.

Answer (score 0):

`String[][]` b is `null`. Look like you should not use `Array` here as you don't know the size up front. You can use an `ArrayList` with some custom object.

Answer (score 0):

> [In the Java programming language, arrays are objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) (§4.3.1),
> are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type
> Object (§4.3.2) [...] A component of an array is accessed by an array access expression
> (§15.13) that consists of an expression whose value is an array
> reference followed by an indexing expression enclosed by [ and ], as
> in A[i].

How do array access expression work? Like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13).

Relevant bit:

> Otherwise, if the value of the array reference expression is null,
> then a NullPointerException is thrown.

Long story short: arrays are objects, and `b` is a reference to an (array) object - like basically everything in Java except primitive types.

A reference can point to *something* or be a `null` reference.

A `null`-reference is something entirely *different* from any other sort of object in the heap, *including an empty array*: you *can't do anything* with it, including trying to access its elements, except assigning a value to it (imagine it as a blank "phone" line in an address book: before calling you have to have a number to call!)

---

**So, you have to first make your reference *point* to an actual array, with**

`b = new String[10][10]`.

**Using this right after**

`String[][] b = null;`

**would be a good idea; or you can just** `String[][] b = new String[10][10]()`.

---

At this point, `b` points to a string array in the heap, and you can *do things* with it.

Note that you have to specify a size.

If you don't know it yet you might be better off with other containers, for example [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which [grows dynamically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).